# Why does Matlab incorrectly return 0 when evaluating an array, but correctly return NaN when evaluating a scalar?

Tags: matlab, nan

Why does the expression for `h(theta)` below sometimes return `0` and sometimes return `NaN`?  `h(theta)` contains a division by zero for `theta = 0` and should always return `NaN`.  If I just ask for `h(0)`, it all works fine.

However, when it evaluates a zero contained in a multi-element array, it returns `h = 0` when it should return `NaN`. But if specifically evaluating only the element that is zero, then it returns `NaN` as it should.

```
>> theta = [0 1]
theta =
     0     1
```

The first element should be `NaN`:

```
>> h = tan(theta)/(1+(tan(theta)/tan(2.*theta)))
h =
     0    5.4220
```

When evaluating the zero element specifically it works correctly:

```
>> h = tan(theta(1))/(1+(tan(theta(1))/tan(2.*theta(1))))
h =
     NaN 

>> h = tan(theta(2))/(1+(tan(theta(2))/tan(2.*theta(2))))
h =
     5.4220
```

Comment: You can put `>>` to the input lines for formatting and better readability.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to do an element-wise division with `./` instead of `/` to get the desired result. This is called the *right array division*.

```
>> h = tan(theta)./(1+(tan(theta)./tan(2.*theta)))
h =
       NaN    5.4220
```

Comment: File this under  "one more thing MATLAB does contrary to how every other language does it, and contrary to normal expectations"